# Carousel slider with lines instead of dots flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to make a Carousel slider in flutter with lines (look at the image), but always finding with dots.

Thanks in advance

[Carousel slider with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVHRZ.png)

Comment: Which library you are using ? show as some code about how the dots are there, from the library or you implemented it ?

Comment: You can try making you custom widget. You can start of with PageView widget to make a basic image slider. Then you can overlap the PageView with the row of lines to get the expected behaviour.  Docs for PageView : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: Indeed I'm using PageView widget , I found a solution with dots_indicator https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with dots_indicator https://pub.dev/packages/dots_indicator

```
DotsIndicator(
              dotsCount: length ?? 0,
              position: currentIndexPage.toDouble(),
              decorator: DotsDecorator(
                  spacing: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3, right: 3),
                  shape: Border(),
                  activeShape: Border(),
                  size: Size(
                      (width - 50) / length, 5),
                  activeSize: Size(
                      (width - 50) / length, 5),
                  color: Colores().blanco(opacity: 0.4),
                  activeColor: Colores().blanco()),
            )
```